# Should I say "One-Click RemovER" or "One-Click RemovAL"?

Tags: grammar, orthography

I'm building a software and am wondering if I should say "remover" or "removal" for its name.

What is the correct way to describe the process? "One Click Color Removal" or "One Click Color Remover"?

Comment: Are you talking about the device or the process??

Comment: @HotLicks the process

Answer (score 1):

In the reference to a process, "removal" shows the action of taking something away.

In reference to a tool, "remover" shows a substance to use for elimination or a thing to move something elsewhere.

Therfore, choice in your question of whether to use "One Click Color Removal" or "One Click Color Remover" depends on how this option functions.

It would seem to be more apparent to users of the program if "Removal" is the name of the option to take "Color" away.

Answer (score 0):

It's a remover, so use *Remover*.

Hyphenate:

- Standard: *One-click*
- Often used in proper names: *One-Click*